# How to catch JQuery UI Accordion Click Event?

Tags: jquery-ui, accordion, jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm using jquery UI's Accordion. When a user switches tabs, I need to hide some images. I've tried a couple of different methods (http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-beforeActivate), but it won't work:

HTML:

```
<div id="accordion">
 <h3>
  <a href="#">
    <span class="menu-item">About</span>
    <img id="slide1" src="/images/sliding-image_1.png"/>
  </a>
 </h3>
 <div>
  .................
 </div>

 <h3><a href="#">................
```

JS:

```
 <script>
 $( "#accordion" ).accordion({ beforeActivate: function( event, ui ) 
                                    {
                                    ui.newHeader.click(function () {
                                        $('#slider1').remove();
                                                      }  
                                    }

               });
</script>
```

OR another one:

```
<script>
$("#accordion").accordion({
  beforeActivate: function(event, ui) {
   if(ui.newHeader) {
    $('h3 a img').remove();
                    }
                                      }
                          });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for...

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    beforeActivate: function( event, ui ) {
        if(ui.newHeader) {
            $(ui.newHeader).find('img').hide();
            $(ui.oldHeader).find('img').show();
        }
    }
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/maheshsapkal/rvRj4/)**

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for

```
h3.ui-accordion-header.ui-state-active
```

If it would be backbone, the code would look something like this:

```
events: {
   'click h3.ui-accordion-header.ui-state-active': 'someFunction'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not in the script. The problem was its location.
All of these scripts work fine.

I wrote this:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   ----------------------------
   Create Accordion
   ----------------------------
  });
</script>
```

And below:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   ----------------------------
    beforeActivate event
   ----------------------------
  });
</script>
```

For some reason, the second script is loaded before the first and did not see the created accordion. So the working script is:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   ----------------------------
   Create Accordion
   ----------------------------
   ----------------------------
   beforeActivate event
   ----------------------------
  });
</script>
```

OR:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var icons = {
    header: "ui-icon-carat-2-n-s",
    headerSelected: ""
};
$("#accordion").accordion({ active:false },{collapsible:true},{icons:icons},{autoHeight:false});

  $("#accordion").accordion(
   {
    beforeActivate: function(event, ui) 
    { 
     $('h3 a img').stop(true); 
     $('h3 a img').fadeOut("medium"); 
    }
   });

});
</script>
```